# Access attribute of XSLT for-each in child attribute selector

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XSL:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/ROOT/Matrix">
    <xsl:if test="count(/ROOT/Groups[@MatrixCode=@Code])>0">
    ...
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The XML rows look like this (They are under the /ROOT namespace):

```
...
<Matrix Code="7.01.05.02.00.00" />
...
<Groups MatrixCode="7.01.05.02.00.00" />
...
```

I would like to test whether the given Matrix entity has any corresponding Groups entities. The above does not seem to work and I presume it is because the scope of @Code is wrong inside the selector for Groups.

How would I access the for-each @Code at that position?

Comment: Have a look at `xsl:key` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#key).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
<xsl:if test="count(../Groups[@MatrixCode = current()/@Code])>0">
```

instead of

```
<xsl:if test="count(/ROOT/Groups[@MatrixCode=@Code])>0">
```

See Transformation at http://xsltransform.net/93nvfcF

Comment: I think the expression should be `[@MatrixCode=current()/@Code]` because without `current()` it will look for a `Code` attribute on the `Groups` element.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this @TimC

Comment: Worked like a charm :-) Thanks!